# JavaScript 'continue' within if statement

Tags: javascript

Within a for loop I can use `break` or `continue`. For example:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  if(i=3){
    continue;   //I know this is absurd to use continue here but it's only for example
  }
}
```

But, what if I want to use `continue` from within a function within a for loop.

For example:

```
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
  theFunction(i);
} 

function theFunction(var x){
  if(x==3){
    continue;
  }
}
```

I know that this will throw an error. But, is there any way to make it work or do something similar?

Comment: It is perfectly possible to call the function outside the context of a loop, in which case `continue` would make absolutely no sense. Therefore it is not possible. The `continue` must lexically be inside the loop it's controlling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use return value of that function and call `continue` based on it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if (theFunction(i)) {
        continue;
    }
}

function theFunction(x){
    if (x == 3) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Btw in your code you have `if(i=3){`, be aware that you need to use `==` or `===`, single equals sign is for assignment.

Comment: oops! my bad. I know the diff between assignment and comparison operator. It was just a typo. By, the way, thanks for the smart solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be, if putting for loop inside the function is not a big deal

```
function theFunction(initial, limit, jump) {
    for (var i = initial; i < limit ; i++) {
        if (i == jump) {
            continue;
        } else {
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
```